# Build history in Jenkins results change over time

Tags: jenkins, tosca

I am trying to setup a jenkins flow with tosca and I got to the point where I can execute my tosca tests via jenkins which are then send to on of the available agents. I really would like to create a dashboard which shows the history and the failed steps of the current run.
In trying to get that up and running I noticed something weird.
Whenever I have a succesfull run it shows up green in jenkins under the builds. If I wait long enough (not entirely sure how long, most of the times its a day) the succesfull build suddenly changed to an unsuccesfull one and thus interfering with the statistics.

I have tried severall thing but it mostly comes down to not really understanding where it get's this data from and how it works. I tried for example making the result.xml file unique by adding the build number to the file but this results in jenkins adding up the two files that now exist (or more if you have more builds). e.g. if result_1 has 3 testcases and result_2 also it will then show up as 6 succesfull testcases in the statistics.

Can anybody point me in the right direction where and how I could solve this?

I am executing the commands via a windows batch command input and the input is as follows:

```
Set Prog="C:\Program Files (x86)\TRICENTIS\Tosca Testsuite\ToscaCommander\ToscaCI\Client\ToscaCIClient.exe"
Set Par= -m distributed -c "C:\ToscaScripting\Test Events\%testEvent%.xml" -r "C:\ToscaScripting\Reports\Result.xml" -e "http://server:81/DistributionServerService/ManagerService.svc"
psexec64 \\server -s -accepteula %Prog% %Par% 
Copy "\\tosca-01\ToscaScripting\Reports\Result.xml" "%WORKSPACE%\Result.xml"
```

Comment: You might search on the [Tricentis Support page](https://support-hub.tricentis.com/open). I found [KB0013520](https://support-hub.tricentis.com/open?id=kb_article_view&sys_kb_id=c52c6bbbdb7413c0b53310284b96198b) which is a step-by-step guide for setting up Tosca CI in Jenkins. Hopefully it has something that can help you.

Comment: Thanks but this is not it. I think that the problem is not with tosca but somewhere in Jenkins and the way it reads the result.xml files. I can succesfully trigger the tests from within jenkins, its just that the test history of the builds is incorrect over time.

Comment: I hope you are able to get it resolved. Remember to add the answer here if you find one!

Comment: I think I got a bit farther but I still don't really understand why it happens or how to solve it. When comparing the builds I noticed that a few where still visible. the numbering went from 136 to 204. So I looked at the difference between build 136 and 137 and I see that the build.xml file is not being generated anymore. I have the feeling that that is part of the problem.